# How to make my two button menu into tabs that show two different html pages below a header

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
body{
 background:url(background.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
}

h1{
 font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
 font-size: 5em;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 25px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h2{
 font-size: 18px;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif;*/
 
}
hr{
 border-color: white;
 margin-left: 200px;
 margin-right: 200px;
}

img{
 float: center;
 width: 20%;
 height: 20%;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}
 li{
  display: inline;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif;
 }

.btn-group{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;

}

.btn-group button {
 align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(135, 138, 138, 0.1); 
    border: none;
    color: white; /* White text */
    padding: 10px 24px; /* Some padding */*/
    cursor: pointer; /* Pointer/hand icon */
    float:  /* Float the buttons side by side */
    box-shadow: 1px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: none;  Prevent double borders 
}

/* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */
.btn-group:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

/* Add a background color on hover */
.btn-group button:hover {
    background-color: rgb(49,52,56);
    border: 1.5px solid rgb(49,52,56);
}

.btn-group button:focus {
 background-color: rgb(49,52,56);
 outline: rgb(49,52,56); 
 border-color: rgb(49,52,56);
 border: 1px solid rgb(49,52,56);

}

.btn-group a{
 color: white;
}

.btn-group a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}

/**/


/* Style the tab */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Portfolio</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tajawal" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body> 

<!--  -->

<div class="heading">
  <h1>Portfolio</h1>
 </div>
<div class="btn-group">
   <div class="tab"><button class="tablinks" onclick="openMenu(event, 'home')"> <a href="index.html">Home</a></button></div>
   <div class="tab"><button class="tablinks2" onclick="openMenu(event, 'portfolio')"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></button></div>
</div>
<div id="home" class="tablinks">
 <h2>My name is  I am a Front End Web developer from . I have a passion for UX/UI and I m currently seeking employment around the country. I am willing to work remote as well as relocate. Take a look at my work and contact me via the info below to learn more.
 <br>
 <img src="treeshot.gif">
  <p>
   <li>HTML5 * </li>
   <LI>CSS3 * </LI>
   <li>JavaScript * </li>
   <li>React * </li>
   <li>Wordpress * </li>
   <li>UX/UI * </li>
   <li>Sketch * </li>
   <li>Adobe Suite * </li>
   <li>Passion and drive to continue learning</li>
  </p>
<br>
<hr>
</h2>
 </h2>
</div>

<div id="Projects" class="tablinks2">
 Projects
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>
```

So far I have made two square buttons into a horizontal bar below my header. I have hyperlinks added to the buttons, but I want to make them tabs so the header does not move and you can cleanly scroll between the two pages with no load time. I will post html and css. Thank you for the help. I have tried using js and css but neither seem to make what it do what I want

Comment: Please start by posting all your code, in a snippet or a CodePen, so that people can quickly edit your code to help you.

Comment: How does your `openMenu()` function looks like. That seems like the most important part of code

Comment: For better readability, please move your text above the code.

Comment: Since you are already using bootstrap. Why not use its tabs. [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/), scroll down to around *JavaScript behavior*

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you're using bootstrap 4. So the best way to do what you want is using nav tabs. Check bootstrap documentation. Here is the example:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist"> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a> </li> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a> </li> <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a> </li> </ul> <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent"> <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">...</div> <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">...</div> <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">...</div> </div>
```

[Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior)